# MVC Razor String Concat

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, razor

I am using Razor to generate a form. I want to create HTML elements based on some value from it's model property.

for example, if a model contains Id property, and I want to generate html tags as follows

```
<input type="hidden" name="1_chk" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="2_chk" />  
<input type="hidden" name="3_chk" />
```

So I used the following syntax, and it failed. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="@Id_chk" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="@(Id)_chk" />
```

Answer (score 10):

another option:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="@(Id + "_chk")" />
```